# Can't get Parse.com framework to work

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, parse-platform, android-studio

I've been trying to put data to Parse Cloud for days and I can't really figure out why it is not working.

I included both libs (Parse and bolts-android) and followed several tutorials on the web. My code is as following:

```
package com.dannyvdz.testapp2;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import com.parse.Parse;
        import com.parse.ParseObject;


public class ParseApplication extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parseapplication);
        Parse.initialize(this, "************", "************");
        // Test creation of object
        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dannyvdz.testapp2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".ParseApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app compiles and runs without errors but no code is being sent to Parse.com. I tried both running the app from Android studio and running it after building it installing it using adb. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated since I think my hairs starting to go grey because of this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why but the application works on my tablet and the android emulator so the problem is my phone. I guess I should factory reset my phone (or wait for my new nexus 6 and work with my tablet in the meantime).
Thanks for all the help!

Update: Several days later I checked Logcat again and I found some messages which make me think of my android adblocker (adfree). I disabled adfree and it started working again. At least I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have internet connection on the (emulator or your device) ??

can you try:

```
testObject.saveEventually();
```

change it with:

```
testObject.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just found out something strange. If I install the app on my tablet it works just fine, however on my phone it doesn't work. My phone runs a stock (rooted) android 4.4.4 and my tablet runs the (rooted) dev preview of android L. I don't know why one works and the other one doesn't but I guess it has something to do with the OS more than the app..